# apacheDS unable to create new entry

Tags: java, apache, ldap

I'm using `Apache Directory Studio 2.0.0` and `ApacheDS 2.0`. After creating a new partition `o=SevenSeans,dc=com`, as said in http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html i'm trying to create a new entry. I select objectClass `organizationalPerson` and type parent `o=SevenSeans,dc=com`, RDN `uid=Name`. Then i click next and type value of `cn` and `sn` attributes. Now i click finish and have exception:

```
Error while creating entry
 - [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES
  javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 19
    Add Request :
Entry
    dn[n]: uid=Name,o=SevenSeans,dc=com
    objectclass: domain
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: extensibleObject
    objectclass: organizationalPerson
    objectclass: person
    uid: Name
    dc: SevenSeans
    sn: sf
    cn: s
: ERR_61 Entry uid=Name,o=SevenSeans,dc=com contains more than one STRUCTURAL ObjectClass: [OBJECT_CLASS ( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.13
 NAME 'domain'
 SUP 'top'
 STRUCTURAL
 MUST 'dc'
 MAY ( 'associatedName' $ 'o' $ 'description' $ 'businessCategory' $ 'seeAlso' $ 'searchGuide' $ 'userPassword' $ 'l' $ 'st' $ 'street' $ 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' $ 'postalAddress' $ 'postalCode' $ 'postOfficeBox' $ 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' $ 'internationaliSDNNumber' $ 'telephoneNumber' $ 'teletexTerminalIdentifier' $ 'telexNumber' $ 'preferredDeliveryMethod' $ 'destinationIndicator' $ 'registeredAddress' $ 'x121Address' )
 )
, OBJECT_CLASS ( 2.5.6.7
 NAME 'organizationalPerson'
 DESC RFC2256: an organizational person
 SUP 'person'
 STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( 'title' $ 'x121Address' $ 'registeredAddress' $ 'destinationIndicator' $ 'preferredDeliveryMethod' $ 'telexNumber' $ 'teletexTerminalIdentifier' $ 'telephoneNumber' $ 'internationaliSDNNumber' $ 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' $ 'street' $ 'postOfficeBox' $ 'postalCode' $ 'postalAddress' $ 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' $ 'ou' $ 'st' $ 'l' )
 )
]]; remaining name 'uid=Name,o=SevenSeans,dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$4.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:669)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1305)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1237)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.createEntry(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:722)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:224)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:124)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

  [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 19
    Add Request :
Entry
    dn[n]: uid=Name,o=SevenSeans,dc=com
    objectclass: domain
    objectclass: top
    objectclass: extensibleObject
    objectclass: organizationalPerson
    objectclass: person
    uid: Name
    dc: SevenSeans
    sn: sf
    cn: s
: ERR_61 Entry uid=Name,o=SevenSeans,dc=com contains more than one STRUCTURAL ObjectClass: [OBJECT_CLASS ( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.4.13
 NAME 'domain'
 SUP 'top'
 STRUCTURAL
 MUST 'dc'
 MAY ( 'associatedName' $ 'o' $ 'description' $ 'businessCategory' $ 'seeAlso' $ 'searchGuide' $ 'userPassword' $ 'l' $ 'st' $ 'street' $ 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' $ 'postalAddress' $ 'postalCode' $ 'postOfficeBox' $ 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' $ 'internationaliSDNNumber' $ 'telephoneNumber' $ 'teletexTerminalIdentifier' $ 'telexNumber' $ 'preferredDeliveryMethod' $ 'destinationIndicator' $ 'registeredAddress' $ 'x121Address' )
 )
, OBJECT_CLASS ( 2.5.6.7
 NAME 'organizationalPerson'
 DESC RFC2256: an organizational person
 SUP 'person'
 STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( 'title' $ 'x121Address' $ 'registeredAddress' $ 'destinationIndicator' $ 'preferredDeliveryMethod' $ 'telexNumber' $ 'teletexTerminalIdentifier' $ 'telephoneNumber' $ 'internationaliSDNNumber' $ 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' $ 'street' $ 'postOfficeBox' $ 'postalCode' $ 'postalAddress' $ 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' $ 'ou' $ 'st' $ 'l' )
 )
]]
```

If i use `import->LDIF` and choose `captain-hook-hierarchy.ldif`

```
Error while importing LDIF
 - [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUES
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 20
    Add Request :
Entry
    dn[n]: ou=people,o=sevenSeas
    objectclass: organizationalUnit
    objectclass: top
    ou: people
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for ou=people,o=sevenSeas]; remaining name 'ou=people,o=sevenSeas'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$4.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:669)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1305)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1237)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.createEntry(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:722)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdifRecord(ImportLdifRunnable.java:464)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdif(ImportLdifRunnable.java:272)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.run(ImportLdifRunnable.java:218)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.StudioConnectionJob.run(StudioConnectionJob.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

[LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 20
    Add Request :
Entry
    dn[n]: ou=people,o=sevenSeas
    objectclass: organizationalUnit
    objectclass: top
    ou: people
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for ou=people,o=sevenSeas]
```

How do I fix this? It's ok to create new entry if i choose `top` class.

Comment: wow, I am just working through the same tutorial. do you have the .ldif file imported with list of sailors?

Comment: ok, i had same problem, i will post answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of issues with that tutorial(spelling, UI looks different, etc) but i have managed to import the sample data and add a new entry.

your error occurs for this reason: `com contains more than one STRUCTURAL ObjectClass`. this is occurring because `domain` and `organizationalPerson` are both structural and will not work together, try removing `domain`. For more info, see [LDAP objectClasses](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/#objectclasses)

To import the `captain-hook-hierarchy.ldif` you need to create a new partition first. The tutorial is inconsistent with naming conventions and is the cause of your error. 
Create a new partition:

```
ID:SevenSeas
Suffix: o=sevenSeas
```

The error you get is because of the `,dc=com` from the tutorial. if you open the .ldif you'll see there is no reference to `,dc=com`.

Next uncheck the `Auto-generate context entry from suffix DN` checkbox. it doesnt create the appropriate attributes for the example. Then add these attributes:

```
o: sevenSeas
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
description: The context entry for suffix o=sevenSeas
```

Save the config.ldif file and restart the server. Then import  `captain-hook-hierarchy.ldif`.
The directory should populate and to add new entries just right-click on a group and `Add new entry`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: AWESOME, you are wizard!!! It's realy work, many thanks. But i have 1 question: There is only `domain` and `organizationalPerson` cannot work together? `organizationalPerson` and `Person` are both structural and work together.

Comment: I am not 100% on which structural objectClasses work together, I only got this working today, perhaps it could be another question

Comment: [This](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/#objectclasses) explains the rules for objectClasses

Comment: Dude I love you. If someone want to fix the documentation you have to create a patch for http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/directory/site/trunk/content/apacheds/basic-ug/ and then submit it in this Jira http://directory.apache.org/issue-tracking.html...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so...

Sionnach733 : you can't have 2 structural ObjectClass in an entry, *except* if they have an inheritance relation. For instance, OrganizationalPerson inherits from Person, so you can have both in an entry (even if adding OrganizationalPerson only implies that *person* is also implicitely added in the entry).

And, yes, those rules are a bit stupid...

Answer (score 1):

The last versión of Apache Directory Studio (Version: 2.0.0.v20151221-M10) has a bug, a missing newline between the generated LDIF records: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-1080

Very easy to fix it, just download a new versión fixed: https://builds.apache.org/job/dir-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the tutorial (http://directory.staging.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html for anyone who want to see the changes before the real site on http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html is on line - that will take a couple of hours).

Thanks for report ! It would be even more convenient to create a JIRA with a description of the typoes (and a patch is even better ! The web site is text based (markdown) and available on http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/site/trunk/content/)

Comment: Hi, I am following link provided above to create a new partition using apache ldap api.....but have failed so far, always getting this

     error....LdapSchemaViolationException: ERR_219 Entry o=sevenseas contains no entryCsn attribute
Can you please help me ......@Emmanuel